# Powershell string matching a specific value from a file (ignore others)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to get the status from a HP RAID controller (using `hpssacli.exe ctrl slot=1 ld all show detail` and piping it into a file.

I just need to check whether `Status: OK` appears in the output. The problem is there are multiple strings that contain `Status: OK`

**output.txt**

```
Smart Array P410 in Slot 1
    array A
      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 10.9 TB
         Fault Tolerance: 5
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 1024 KB
         Status: Interim Recovery Mode
         Caching:  Enabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
         Disk Name: /dev/sda
         Mount Points: /storage 10.9 TB Partition Number 2
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache
```

I was trying to run the command `sls "Status: " .\output.txt` but I receive 3 matches:

```
output.txt:13:         Status: Interim Recovery Mode
output.txt:15:         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
output.txt:19:         OS Status: LOCKED
```

Is there a way with Powershell to do a regex style match to only match where the string is *not* a character, followed by `Status:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match based on that string containing only spaces before your output using

```
Select-String "(^\s*)Status: " .\output.txt
```

or match exactly 9 spaces before the word Status.

```
 Select-String "(^\s{9})Status: " .\output.txt
```